# Shell copy a file but changing extension

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I am pretty new to linux and shell and I wold like to copy a file to a location passed by an argument but change its extension, the windows version of that would be

```
copy .\a\b\c.pre %~dpn2.i

    d --> get the drive letter only
    p --> get the path only
    n --> get the file name only
```

So my **question is** : How can I get the full path of a file passed by argument and add a file extension to it?

The shell command would look like `cp ./a/b/c.pre [$2 path but with extension .i]`

Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to copy a file and change the extension, why not simply cp /path/c.pre /path/c.i ?

Comment: @JazzCat because the file has to have a special name that is passed in the args

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.src; do
    cp "${file}" "${tgt_dir}"/"${file/%.src/.tgt}"
done
```

This will simply rename all the files with extension .src in the source folder to .tgt in the target folder. You need to set the target folder in your script

Comment: Thanks, but how do I extract the target dir from an argument? The passed arg would be something like `/dev/sda1/a/b/c.XXX` and I would like to copy the file to `/dev/sda1/a/b/c.i`